# Deleted Facebook account still shows up in search results?

Tags: facebook, account-management

I deleted my Facebook account and after 14 days, I got an e-mail that confirmed my Facebook account was deleted. However, my profile still shows up in Facebook's search results, albeit the account is empty except for education, work, and location. I tried to login again but it says the email is not associated with any account. Anybody knows how I can remove my deleted account from the search results?

Comment: Whose search results? Most likely it's just a caching issue and you just need to be patient.

Comment: When I search for myself from a friend's account.

Comment: A Facebook search, then.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I have just closed 2 personal and 2 fanpage accounts (business accounts) and even though they are unpublished, when I search them from a different facebook account, they show up in the search with the images and likes. However when I click on the drop down, it also says it doesn't exist anymore. I would like it completely deleted from the search too!

Answer (score 4):

Just to be sure, you used this form https://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=delete_account and now your account is still up. It appears in the search results and the profile is still there.

1. Go to the profile
2. Select Report/Block
3. Choose "This is my old account"
4. Select "I want to close this account"

You should get a message "The reported timeline will be deactivated after a review."

---

Other things to note: Are you sure it's not a second account you have set up?

See: [Scripting News: Arrgh Facebook is lying about me](http://scripting.com/stories/2011/11/28/facebookFraud.html) where Dave Winer incorrectly calls Facebook a fraud for not realizing the accounts that appeared in the search results were duplicates made by other users.

So make sure that the account that shows up in the search result is indeed yours. If a user can make a friend request and it can be called from the graph

`graph.facebook.com/facebookid`

Then it is most likely not deleted or never was initiated for deletion. Review the email you used with your account and the email that you used to search for the account in question if you cannot remember your Facebook ID.